# How to fix this error : Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate configuration file.Please verify databse..........rnate.cfg.xml

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I tried to create a Hibernate project but I have a follow problem:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/DemoHibernate</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml.In that,I use the jtds library:
        DemoHibernate: my databse in sql server 2005
        sa: my username in sql server 2005
        root: my password
when I right-click ->New->Other->Hibernate-> Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard .Follow error appear:

" ***Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate configuration file.Please verify databse connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml*** "

I thinked the cause from jtds library because If I use content of hibernate.cfg.xml as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

=> All is well

Who can help me,please?